# Why is this date validation not working with Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am using Formik/Yup to validate a form, and I'm trying to validate a birthday.

Here's my form:

```
let initialState = [
  // { dateOfBirth: "2019-05-07" },
  // { dateOfBirth: "2019-05-07" }
];
return (
  <div>
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialState}
      validationSchema={Schema}
      onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      render={({ handleSubmit, isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {childrenToOrder.map((item, index) => {
            let borderBottom = `1px solid black`;
            // no border on the last item
            if (childrenToOrder.length - 1 === index) {
              borderBottom = "none";
            }
            return (
              <div
                key={index}
                style={{
                  marginBottom: `${scale.s4}rem`,
                  paddingBottom: `${scale.s4}rem`,
                  borderBottom: borderBottom
                }}
              >
                <h2
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "24px",
                    marginBottom: `${scale.s3 + scale.s1}rem`
                  }}
                >
                  {item.firstName}
                </h2>
                <Field
                  type="date"
                  label="Date of birth"
                  name={`${index}.dateOfBirth`}
                  placeholder="27/01/2000"
                  component={Input}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit Form
          </button>
        </Form>
```

And here's my `Scehma`:

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape([
  {
    dateOfBirth: Yup.date().required("Required")
  }
]);
```

When I console.log the values of the form I get back the following:

`[{dateOfBirth: "2019-05-07"}, {dateOfBirth: "2019-05-07"}]`

Shouldn't that work?

What I am trying to achieve is to validate a date of birth, so a date has to be entered into the Input. Later I will want to make sure it's not a date in the future - but can't even get the validation to work yet!

Any ideas?

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/94n93083vw)

Comment: seems like your input box name is like `0['dateOfBirth']` but you are validating for `dateOfBirth`. Using numbers to start properties is a bad idea BTW. If you want to put items in an array, use `dateOfBirth[0]` or [<FieldArray>](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray)